# React Native WebView and login by Facebook and Google

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, webview, facebook-login

I use the WebView component in my mobile app. It shows my webpage on which I logged in with Facebook and Google. Facebook is authorized, but it doesn’t bring me back to the app and I don’t get any data in the app. At Google, I have the same problem. Has anyone ever had a similar problem?

```
Mobile: 
 "react": "18.2.0",
 "react-native": "^0.69.2",
 "react-native-webview": "11.22.7",

Web: 
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
```

My webview component looks like this:

```
 <WebView
      source={{ uri: src }}
      ref={webviewref}
      containerStyle={[
        styles.webviewStyle,
        { display: isLoading ? 'none' : 'flex' },
      ]}
      onHttpError={(syntheticEvent) => {
        const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent;
        ViewErrorScreen(nativeEvent.statusCode);
      }}
      onLoadProgress={(e: WebViewProgressEvent) => {
        setProgress(parseFloat(e.nativeEvent.progress.toFixed(2)));
      }}
      onLoadStart={() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
      }}
      onError={() => {
        dispatch(setWarningStatus(true));
        dispatch(openWebview(false));
      }}
      allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures
      onLoadEnd={() => setIsLoading(false)}
      scrollEnabled={true}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      scalesPageToFit={true}
      allowFileAccess={true}
      onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
      allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
      userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"

    />
```

Comment: Are you trying to use facebook/ google authentication to login in to your app?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to url changes in webview. Add a condition, if it's a success - close your webview and redirect to screen that you wish.

```
onLoadStart={(e) => this.onNavigationStateChange(e)}

onNavigationStateChange = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    console.log(nativeEvent.url); // here is a webview dynamic url
    if (nativeEvent.url === successUrl) {
      //    close webview
    }
}
```